# Make random quiz app using array

Tags: java, android

i am trying to make random quiz app using array, so I want to keep the repetition. Can you suggest some ways I can achieve this? I have added the code below for what I have. I am not sure what I need to do.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz);
    QuestionMaker();
}
```

This function will make a bunch of questions:

```
//funtion makes the load of the question

public void QuestionMaker(){
    QText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_questions);
    Qgroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.Group_radio);
    btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_next);

    final ArrayList<String> distractorList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Collections.addAll(distractorList, Options);


//first time of filling the form

    int length = question.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        quiz.add(new QuestionAndAnswer(question[i], answer[i], distractorList.subList(i * 3, (i + 1) * 3)));
    Collections.shuffle(quiz);
    fillInQuestion();


//clicking the radio button this happen


    Qgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            makefinish++;
            QuestionAndAnswer qna = quiz.get(currentQuestion);
            qna.selectedAnswer = ((RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId)).getText().toString();

            if (qna.selectedAnswer == qna.answer) {
                correctcounter++;
                //correct message

            }
            if (!(qna.selectedAnswer == qna.answer)) {
//wrong answer message
            }

}

//function that makes the filling

public void fillInQuestion() {
    QuestionAndAnswer qna = quiz.get(currentQuestion);`enter code here`
    QText.setText(qna.question);

    int count = Qgroup.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        ((RadioButton) Qgroup.getChildAt(i)).setText(qna.allAnswers.get(i));


}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to do this. Here is one:

You can randomly choose a question by randomly generating a number between 0 and the number of elements in the array. Afterwards you can display that question on the screen. After user answers the question you want to refresh the screen and load a different question. Also you should create another array that will hold a list of numbers that were already generated, and check the question number to make sure you didn't already ask that question before.

To answer your question about repetition: change the text and answer choices after user inputs an answer to first question. This logic can also be in a loop or some sort.